Playwright: Missing Dependencies for Running Browsers on AWS EC2 (Ubuntu)
I'm trying to use Playwright in a Python project to automate browser actions. The setup works perfectly on my local machine, but I encounter issues with missing system dependencies when deploying the project on an AWS EC2 instance.
Environment:

AWS EC2 Instance: Ubuntu 20.04
Python: 3.12
Playwright Version: 1.45.1

Steps Taken:
Installed Playwright:
pip install playwright

Installed Playwright browsers:
python -m playwright install

Tried installing system dependencies:
sudo npx playwright install-deps

Error Messages:
I still receive the following error message when trying to run Playwright on the AWS EC2 instance:
BrowserType.launch: Executable doesn't exist at /root/.cache/ms-playwright/webkit-2035/pw_run.sh\n╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗\n║ Looks like Playwright was just installed or updated.       ║\n║ Please run the following command to download new browsers: ║\n║                                                            ║\n║     playwright install                                     ║\n║                                                            ║\n║ <3 Playwright Team                                         ║\n╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝

Here is the screenshot of the error:
Error on Postman
Code Snippet:
import asyncio
import re
import logging
import time
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright

async with async_playwright() as p:
        browser = await p.webkit.launch(headless=True)
        for attempt in range(retries):
            try:
                context = await browser.new_context(user_agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3")
                page = await context.new_page()
                
                for nav_attempt in range(retries):
                    try:
                        await page.goto(url, timeout=30000)  # Reduced timeout for faster retries
                        logger.info(f"Navigated to {url}")
                        break
                    except Exception as e:
                        logger.error(f"Navigation attempt {nav_attempt + 1}/{retries} failed: {e}")

The virtual environment is activated before running the commands.
The setup works perfectly on my local machine.
Reinstalling Playwright and the dependencies multiple times on the AWS EC2 instance did not resolve the issue.
How can I resolve these missing dependencies and successfully run Playwright on my AWS EC2 instance?
